# How do I use search on nested json using wildcards?

Tags: json, google-bigquery

How can I use bigquery search() on a nested json using a wildcard in my string literal?

Example below, note the % wildcard at the end of the search string. There is a search index defined on the logrec json column which would be nice to use.

```
with x as (
    select to_json('{"roleArn":"arn:iam::6789","roleSessionName":"abc123"}') as logrec
    union all
    select to_json('{"roleArn":"arn:iam::5678","roleSessionName":"abc124"}') as logrec
)
select * from x where search(logrec,'abc12%');
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't intend to you the `search` function inside `where` clause, below query will return you `boolean` values `true/false` if the pattern is found in the json data.

Please note, the query below also caters for capitalised values in input data - see record 3.

```
 with x as (
    select to_json('{"roleArn":"arn:iam::6789","roleSessionName":"abc123"}') as logrec
    union all
    select to_json('{"roleArn":"arn:iam::5678","roleSessionName":"abc124"}') as logrec
    union all
    select to_json('{"roleArn":"arn:iam::5678","roleSessionName":"ABC1"}') as logrec
    union all
    select to_json('{"roleArn":"arn:iam::5678","roleSessionName":"xyz123"}') as logrec
)
select *,search(logrec,r'\"abc12\"',analyzer=>'PATTERN_ANALYZER',analyzer_options=>'{"patterns": ["[a-zA-Z.]*"]}') as search_result
from x
```

See screenshot of the output. Hope this helps!

[image]